# Dynamically populating cells depending on page title

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I'm trying to make it so the program checks the navigation title, then populates the cells accordingly. This would be easy enough with hardcoded arrays but using a Core Data object is making things tough.

Initializers - 3 products for each company and an empty array to set them to after checking the page title:

```
let defaultProductsApple = ["iPhone", "iPad", "Macbook"]
let defaultProductsGoogle = ["Search", "Firebase", "Magic Leap"]
let defaultProductsFacebook = ["Facebook", "Instagram", "WhatsApp"]
let defaultProductsTesla = ["Model S", "Model X", "PowerWall"]
let defaultProductsTwitter = ["Twitter", "Periscope", "Vine"]
var defaultProducts = [String]()
```

viewDidLoad - check the page title and populate the empty array, then set to Core Data for persistence when deleting:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    // Navbar stuff
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleBackButton))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleAdd))

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Product", in: managedContext)!

        switch self.navigationItem.title! {
        case "Apple":
            defaultProducts = defaultProductsApple
        case "Google":
            defaultProducts = defaultProductsGoogle
        case "Twitter":
            defaultProducts = defaultProductsTwitter
        case "Tesla":
            defaultProducts = defaultProductsTesla
        case "Facebook":
            defaultProducts = defaultProductsFacebook
        default:
            defaultProducts = defaultProductsApple
        }

        for productName in defaultProducts {
            let product = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,insertInto: managedContext)
            product.setValue(productName, forKey: "name")
            products.append(product)
        }
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            tableView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

}
```

And finally set the labels in cellForRow:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! Cell
    let product = products[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = product.value(forKey: "name") as? String

    return cell
}
```

The cells populate as they should on the first try - i.e. if I tap on "Apple" in the previous screen, the cells show me Apple's 3 products. But then if I go back and tap on "Google", the cells now show Apple's 3 products as well as Google's 3 products, and so on and so forth.

How can I make it so that `cell.textLabel?.text = product.value(forKey: "name") as? String` ONLY loads that company's products?

EDIT: `viewWillAppear` and the `save` methods:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //1
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //2
    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Product")

    //3
    do {
        products = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}




func save(name: String) {

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Product",
                                   in: managedContext)!

    let product = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                  insertInto: managedContext)

    product.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        products.append(product)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Final Edit - setting all the defaults in one go

```
// Default 5 companies at launch - user can delete/add/edit
func setDefaults() {

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let defaultValues = ["firstRun" : true]
    userDefaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)

    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "firstRun") {

        let defaultProducts = ["Apple" : ["iPhone", "iPad", "Macbook"],
                               "Google" : ["Search", "Firebase", "Magic Leap"],
                               "Facebook" : ["Facebook", "Instagram", "WhatsApp"],
                               "Tesla" : ["Model S", "Model X", "PowerWall"],
                               "Twitter" : ["Twitter", "Periscope", "Vine"]]

        let companyEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Company", in: managedContext)!
        let productEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Product", in: managedContext)!


        // Setting the default company data (name, logo, and stockPrice)
        let url = URL(string: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol%2C%20Ask%2C%20YearHigh%2C%20YearLow%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22TWTR%22%2C%22TSLA%22%2C%20%22FB%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                let json = JSON(data: data!)
                if let quotes = json["query"]["results"]["quote"].array {
                    for quote in quotes {
                        let symbol = quote["symbol"].stringValue
                        let name = NSLocalizedString(symbol, comment:"")
                        let ask = quote["Ask"].stringValue
                        let company = NSManagedObject(entity: companyEntity,insertInto: managedContext)
                        company.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                        company.setValue(name, forKey: "logo")
                        company.setValue(ask, forKey: "stockPrice")
                        companies.append(company)
                        print(json)
                    }

                    // Setting the default products - should I be doing this here too?
                    let companyProducts = defaultProducts[companyName]

                    // iterate through all those products names...
                    for productName in companyProducts {
                        // create the corresponding Product:
                        let product = NSManagedObject(entity: productEntity,insertInto: managedContext)
                        // set its name attribute...
                        product.setValue(productName, forKey: "name")
                        // then set the relationship to the relevant Company...
                        product.setValue(company, forKey: "company")
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        do {
                            try managedContext.save()
                            vc.tableView.reloadData()
                            userDefaults.set(false, forKey: "firstRun")
                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("The data couldn't be loaded")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other code that updates the `products` array, perhaps by executing a fetch request, eg. in `viewWillAppear` or one of the other lifecycle methods?

Comment: @pbasdf Yes, I edited my question to include `viewWillAppear` as well as the `save` method. Any help will be massively appreciated!

Comment: Thanks - that explains what you are observing.  The fetch request (in viewWillAppear) fetches everything; you need some way to distinguish the Apple's products from Google's (and everyone else's).  You could either do that by adding a 'company' attribute to the Product entity, or by adding a relationship to a 'Company' entity.  You also need to amend your code to load those defaults only once.  I'll add a full answer later...

Comment: @pbasdf Thank you, I'll be ready to vote up that answer as soon as you post it! I'm just getting started learning Core Data so this will be a great learning experience. I've been meaning to add a relationship between my Company and Product entities but wasn't sure how to work it in or what good it would do me. I've posted screenshots of my data model if it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by creating a relationship from `Company` to `Product`, and name it "products".  Each `Company` can have many `Products`, so make the relationship "to-many".  Likewise create a relationship from `Product` to `Company`, and name it "company".  Each `Product` is related to only one `Company` (I assume), so make the relationship "to-one", and set its inverse to be "products".

To make life easier, add the default values at the same time that you create your default `Company` data (not sure where you are now doing that).  Note that I have changed your five arrays of products into a dictionary (`defaultProducts`), with the company name as the key: this makes it easier to load into CoreData in one go:

```
func setDefaults() {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let defaultValues = ["firstRun" : true]
    userDefaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)

    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "firstRun") {
        let defaultProducts = ["Apple" : ["iPhone", "iPad", "Macbook"],
                               "Google" : ["Search", "Firebase", "Magic Leap"],
                               "Facebook" : ["Facebook", "Instagram", "WhatsApp"],
                               "Tesla" : ["Model S", "Model X", "PowerWall"],
                               "Twitter" : ["Twitter", "Periscope", "Vine"]]

        let companyEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Company", in: managedContext)!
        let productEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Product", in: managedContext)!

        // Setting the default company data (name, logo, and stockPrice)
        let url = URL(string: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20symbol%2C%20Ask%2C%20YearHigh%2C%20YearLow%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22TWTR%22%2C%22TSLA%22%2C%20%22FB%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                let json = JSON(data: data!)
                if let quotes = json["query"]["results"]["quote"].array {
                    for quote in quotes {
                        let symbol = quote["symbol"].stringValue
                        let name = NSLocalizedString(symbol, comment:"")
                        let ask = quote["Ask"].stringValue
                        let company = NSManagedObject(entity: companyEntity,insertInto: managedContext)
                        company.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                        company.setValue(name, forKey: "logo")
                        company.setValue(ask, forKey: "stockPrice")
                        companies.append(company)
                        // Move the default products code here:
                        let companyProducts = defaultProducts[name]
                        // iterate through all those products names...
                        for productName in companyProducts {
                            // create the corresponding Product:
                            let product = NSManagedObject(entity: productEntity, insertInto:managedContext)
                            // set its name attribute...
                            product.setValue(productName, forKey: "name")
                            // then set the relationship to the relevant Company...
                            product.setValue(company, forKey: "company")
                        }

                        print(json)
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        do {
                            try managedContext.save()
                            vc.tableView.reloadData()
                            userDefaults.set(false, forKey: "firstRun")
                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("The data couldn't be loaded")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

In your view controller, you can remove the code to set the defaults products from `viewDidLoad`.

You are currently using the navigation item title to determine which Company's products you should display.  So in `viewWillAppear`, you need to amend your fetch to limit the results.  Use a `predicate`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //1
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    //2
    let companyToDisplay = self.navigationItem.title!
    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Product")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"company.name == %@",companyToDisplay)    
    //3
    do {
        products = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: You're my hero right now, thanks so much for such a thorough answer! Definitely helping me understand how to work with Core Data more efficiently!

Comment: Quick update - I'm trying to work this solution into the same place where I set the default companies (the app launches with those 5 default companies, with 3 products each, then let the user delete and add as they wish). I love the idea of using a dictionary to assign each company's products, I'm just not sure how to work it into my function. I pasted the `setDefaults()` function at the bottom of my question if you'd like to take a look (or I can make a separate question), but don't sweat it if you don't have time, you've been a massive help already!

Comment: @d0xi45 I've edited my answer - you were very close: setting the products needs to be inside the `for quote in quotes {}` loop, in order to set them for each company.

Comment: Alright, everything is working perfectly now! Although for some reason I have to run the app twice for the defaults to show up (running just once gives an empty table view, then running again everything shows up), but I'll figure that out in time. Thanks again for guiding me through this, I'll do my best to pay it forward when I sharpen my own skills!

Answer (score 0):

Before you perform your `switch self.navigationItem.title! {`, reset your array like this:

```
defaultProducts.removeAll()
```

Your viewController is likely not being deallocated, so the `defaultProducts` array retains its previous items. By clearing it before you populate it, that issue should go away.

Comment: I just tried this (put in `viewDidLoad` before the switch statement) and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I return `products.count`, products being `var products = [NSManagedObject]()`